# Would be “жив-здоров” considered equivalent to "alive and kicking"?

Tags: discussion

Please do not send me to the other (closed) question on “жив-здоров” and please do not tell me about english.SE. When I originally proposed this Russian-English exchange site (few of you would remember that), the idea was to discuss the link between usage of the two languages, not Russian language and its usage. Anyway, it does not sound right that questions I originally had in mind (like that in the title) need now be classed as off-topic.

Comment: This should be discussed on meta I believe.

Comment: This is not a question, it's a statement that belongs on meta, if anywhere.

Comment: @kotekzot I disagree. It is a question, but could be phrased in a less limiting way. E.g. "What is an equivalent phrase to 'alive and kicking'?" (SE also provides the ability to answer your own question at the same time as asking in order to simply share knowledge).

Comment: @Lisa it's not a question because the question body is an irrelevant rant.

Comment: @kotekzot Fair call, but I can't see why the original question was shot down. In its current form this question doesn't make sense on Russian Meta either. Perhaps it should have just been closed.

Comment: @Lisa Only the title is out of place. I can't fix it though. The rest is Meta material.

Answer (score 3):

Andrey, I don't want this to sound bad so take my words in a good way. :) Although you're the one who proposed the Russian Q&A, you're not the one who decides what to do with it. The community does. That includes also you, of course, but excludes you from being the only one who does decide.

Now, there are other Language-related sites. They all fit a certain format, and this site, being a language-related site itself, is not exempt from this. By the way, a site that only discusses the differences between Russian and English would be really limiting and constraining. This site can be much more.

According to the definition phase questions, your question should be fine. If someone wants to deem them as off topic, a new Meta question should be proposed asking the community to express their opinion.

Answer (score 0):

I think here on meta you are asking if this question is okay. And I would say **yes it's a valid question** -- just as helpful to English natural speakers learning Russian as Russian natural speakers learning English.